# Prove the Dirac Delta Function satisfies $ x\frac{\mathrm{d} \delta(x)}{\mathrm{d} x} = -\delta(x) $

Tags: calculus, integration, dirac-delta

$ x\frac{\mathrm{d} \delta(x)}{\mathrm{d} x} = -\delta(x)$

I've been told that this answer involves integration by parts. I began like this:

$\int x\frac{\mathrm{d} \delta(x)}{\mathrm{d} x} = x\delta(x) - \int\delta(x)$

or

$ x\frac{\mathrm{d} \delta(x)}{\mathrm{d} x} = \frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x}(x\delta(x)) - \delta(x)$

So it seems that all I have to do is show that $x\delta(x) =0$ or $\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x}( x\delta(x)) =0$

EDIT: But  $x\delta(x) =0$ when $x=0$ and also when $x$ is any other number. so I just answered my own dumb question.

Griffiths. Introduction to Electrodynamics. Third Edition page 49. Problem 1.45 part a.

Comment: Actually I'm looking at what this says and now I see how it is true. I should probably delete this question. Its embarrassingly simple.

Comment: You may just apply both sides to any $\varphi \in \mathcal S$,  the Schwarz class.

Comment: But  $x\delta(x) =0$ when $x=0$ and also when $x$ any other number. so I just answered my own dumb question.

Comment: @mathmath12 Technically what you have just said is not correct, roughly because you don't know that $\delta(0)$ is not "so big" that $x \delta(x)$ is nonzero. Note that $x \delta'(x)$ *is* nonzero, so this is not a trivial matter. The better answer is that when $d$ is a compactly supported distribution or $f$ is a smooth compactly supported function, $\langle d',f \rangle = -\langle d,f' \rangle$. In the case of the Dirac delta it is indeed a compactly supported distribution (its support is $\{ 0 \}$, as you might expect).

Comment: @mathmath12 In other words, when the distribution or the function is compactly supported, the boundary term vanishes, just as happens with ordinary functions.

Comment: @Ian I don't know anything about distribution theory. My knowledge of the Dirac Function is limited to how it is presented in Griffiths Intro to Electrodynamics. and im assuming he doesn't expect us to go beyond that level.

Comment: @Ian. Now that I look it. even from  my point of view it isn't obvious. because I'm basically multiplying "infinity" (the delta function at 0)  by 0 and saying that is 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets look at $(\delta'(x)x,\psi(x))$

Where $\psi(x)$ is a suitable test function and (,) denotes the inner product (remember that we can interpret an distribution as a linear functional over the space of test functions) then we can apply the general rule $(\delta', f)=-(\delta, f')$.

Furthermore we can push $x$, or more generally speaking any smooth function onto the testfunction (roughly speaking, because this gives another one) and so we get:

$$
(\delta'(x)x,\psi(x))=-(\delta(x),(x \psi(x))')=-(\delta(x),\psi(x)+x \psi'(x))=-(\delta(x),\psi(x))+\underbrace{(\delta(x),x\psi'(x))}_{=0}
$$

the last equation follows from the fact that $x\psi'(x)$ is again a testfunction with the propertiy $0\psi'(0)=0$ and therefore $(\delta,0)=0$

Maybe we should add the point, that every testfunction is bounded, so that my last line is really justified now :)

Edit:

To make this answer look at little bit more "physical" one replaces the inner product by $\int dx$ then everything should look a little bit more familiar... Furthermore just think about this test functions as functions which are as "well behaved" as necessary to allow all the manipilations

Comment: thank you. I want to understand this explanation. Im new to this approach. im wondering if you think my answer would satisfy Griffiths at his level of presentation.

Comment: hi see my edit.

Comment: I can sort of follow this. Do you have any suggestions for reading material on this (preferably free online)?

Comment: i think this is a nice primer http://www.math.umd.edu/~trivisa/distributions.pdf
Otherwise http://press.princeton.edu/titles/8452.html has by far the best treatment of the subject tailored to the needs of physicists

Comment: @ tired  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you know about a distribution comes from how it acts on test functions. So if you want to prove anything about distributions, you should use an arbitrary test function, say $\phi$. In terms of physical intuition, I tend to think of a distribution as an object with some unknown properties and test functions as "observations" of the object, like the [blind men and the elephant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_men_and_an_elephant). YMMV of course.

The definition of the derivative of a distribution $f$ comes from integration by parts: $f'(\phi)(x) = - f(\phi')(x)$. Since integration by parts comes from the product rule and (you should prove this) distributional derivatives satisfy the product rule, we should suspect something like:
$$ \frac{d}{dx}(x\delta) = \delta + x\frac{d\delta}{dx}$$
So now, as you observe, $$(x\delta)(\phi)(x) = \int x\delta\phi\ dx = \int \delta x\phi\ dx = (x\phi)(0) = 0.$$

(I mostly answered this to add a bit of background and philosophy about distributions.)

Comment: Anyone can help to expand the neat notation $f'(\phi)(x) = - f(\phi')(x)$ in a fundamental form?